# Please help: HBase doesn't detect .Meta table

Tags: hbase, meta

I have been using an HBase cluster of 10 PCs for a while. Everything had been working fine before i stopped the cluster last night. But when i started the cluster this morning, I noticed that HBase master didn't detect the .Meta table so .Meta table doesn't appear in catalog table with the root table at hbase master port 60010. I did many restarts but it didn't work. What is the problem? and how can i fix it?

Here I pasted the Logs: [Logs: Zookeeper, Hbase-Master, HDFS NameNode, YARN RecourceManager](http://pastebin.ca/2394606)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: My HBase master was failing to start because Zookeeper was giving it an incorrect location for where the -ROOT- table was located. I fixed it by clearing zookeeper:
1. `Hbase zkcli`
2. `rmr /hbase/root-region-server`
3. `rmr /hbase/unassigned`
4. then by restarting hbase master everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your NameNode is in `safemode`. Issue this command to come out of it :

```
bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Restart your HBase after this and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but i wish you had helped me earlier. Due to being short of time i deleted and recreated my DataNode directories and reformatted my NameNode before your response. Unfortunately i didn't have time to check if it works. Now i can't use the lab for two days.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry for that. But you must consider this as the last option. If you face any problem go through the logs first. In 99% cases you would find logs helpful in problem diagnosis. Good luck with your lab.

Comment: Failed again! I rebuilt my hdfs cluster, yet it doesn't work. Then i issued your command and got out of safemode and restarted services but it didn't work and there is no sign of .META. table.
Help me please.

Comment: That is the reason I had said that you should solve the problem rather than bypassing it. What's the error message now?Logs?

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete hmaster log?I can't find any error message in it. Also, are your hadoop daemons running fine?

Comment: Yes this is the complete log, the daemons are running fine too. This info may help: 
1. The -ROOT- region is stuck in transition.
2. .META. table exists but it is not assigned to Catalog Table.

Comment: I issued this command:`sudo -u hbase hbase hbck -repair` and pasted the terminal result [here](http://pastebin.ca/2400223). I wish it helps.

Comment: Looks like there is some problem with the regionserver holding your mete info. Could you plz show me your RS logs as well?

Comment: Sure, [Here are the DataNode and HBase-RegionServer Logs](http://pastebin.ca/2400235).

Comment: I think the problem is in the **connection between Zookeeper and Regionservers**, would you please take a look at this log. [RegionServer Log](http://paste2.org/YC24jUCt)